# Flex 4.6 : Pass parameters from flex to Web Services

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Im using flex 4.6 mobile application . i want to send base64 String of image from flex to wcf web services . i try to connect to WSDL web service from the Data/services and pass the url of the services and it read the services and methods then generate Service call to pass string but not working . 
now i try to connect through web services classes

```
            public function useWebService( base64byte:String):void {    
            ws = new WebService(); 
            ws.wsdl="http://10.0.0.36/Service1.svc?wsdl"; 
            ws.SubmitData2.addEventListener("result", echoResultHandler); 
            ws.addEventListener("fault", faultHandler); 
            ws.loadWSDL(); 

            ws.echoArgs(base64byte); 

            ws.getOperation("SubmitData2").send(base64byte);
            var params:Object = new Object(); 
            params.imageData = base64byte;

            ws.SubmitData2(base64byte);
            ws.send(base64byte); 


        }
```

i not understand this well i searched for samples and edit to it but this method it doesnt work , i want to know how to connect to SubmitData2 method in the WCF servise to pass to the paramters , and save the image

SubmitData2 method in WCF

```
  public void SubmitData2(String data)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/" + new Guid().ToString() + ".jpeg"), bytes);

    }
```

please help , Thanks in advance for any idea .

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does your Actionscript code throw an exception when you get to `ws.SubmitData2.addEventListener("result", echoResultHandler);`?  Does it execute `faultHandler`?  Does it fail silently?  Can you call SubmitData2 manually (e.g. from Fiddler) and get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by
- Data/services in the flashbuilder and pass the url of the services 
- it read the services and methods 
- generate Service call and build the project in the IIS through the IP address to see it form the mobile